# HDFS Federation: Configuring HA using same node as an active node and standby node

Tags: cloudera-cdh, cloudera-manager

I am trying to configure HA in a HDFS Federation using Cloudera Manager(http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera/en/documentation/cdh5/v5-1-x/CDH5-High-Availability-Guide/cdh5hag_hdfs_ha_software_config.html)

Since I have a federated HDFS configuration, I have multiple namenodes catering to different namespaces. These name nodes are hosted on different physical nodes in the cluster. For configuring HA, I am trying to setup a corresponding standby name node for each of these different name nodes.

Suppose I have a configuration like the following (NN = NameNode, SNN = StandbyNameNode):

Active NameNodes: NN1, NN2, NN3
Standby NameNodes: SNN1, SNN2, SNN3

Assume that I have 3 physical nodes in the cluster. Does Cloudera Manager allow me to host an active namenode and a standby namenode (for a different active namenode) on the same physical host?

Will the following configuration be supported?
Node 1: NN1 and SNN3
Node 2: NN2 and SNN1
Node 3: NN3 and SNN2

Thanks in advance for your responses!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cloudera Manager doesn't support adding multiple NameNodes to the same physical host, so the configuration you listed won't be possible. This is by design to avoid overloading the NameNode host.

You'll need to enlarge the cluster to 6 nodes if you'd like to enable High-Availability for the 3 separate namespaces.